# Package Manager Console wont inialize

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to user the package manager console it will not get past `Initializing PowerShell Host...`.

[image: here]

I try to open PowerShell directly and I get [image: This]

I have had this before and eventually had to restore computer to prior date. I tried that and it changed nothing. Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Information under event viewer says

> Windows PowerShell has started an IPC listening thread on process: 22300 in AppDomain: DefaultAppDomain.

Comment: I was told to look at event log by a friend, i did however i don't really know what i am looking at.

Comment: In the event viewer, go to Applications and Services => Microsoft => Windows => Powershell => Operational, then try to see if there are any warnings or errors. On a side note, do you have a Powershell profile?

Comment: I don't know what a powershell profile is

Comment: there are a lot of warnings from 8/12

Comment: If you don't know what that is, then you most likely don't have one :) It's a script that users can add, that is executed whenever a new PS console is started. That sometimes causes performance issues at startup, especially if the script accesses network resources. Hence the question.

Comment: can you try to execute the following as admin: `start-job { Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted } -RunAs32 | wait-job | Receive-Job`

Comment: I can not type in powershell at all

Comment: anyone else any ideas?

Comment: I was going to suggest `powershell.exe -noprofile` to exclude a nuget or all hosts profile that's stuck, but guess it's too late. :-)

Comment: I couldn't type in PowerShell at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Restored computer again and this worked. I tried this once, it didn't work, but it did on third time of trying.

Comment: what do you mean by restored computer?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cache did the trick for me, no idea why though.

[image]